# Unable to iterate array of dictionary as it says "Value to type 'Any' has no subscripts"

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdictionary

I want to iterate array of dictionary but it gives error that "Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts". I just followed answer provide in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875394/swift-iterate-array-of-dictionaries)

Here is the array of dictionaries in debug mode: 
[image: ScreenShotOfArray]

Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
if let markersArray = appDelegate.markersArray{
            for marker in markersArray{
                let name = marker["name"] as? [String:Any]
            }
        }
```

Also tried this way but still doesn't work:

```
if let markersArray = appDelegate.markersArray{
                for marker in markersArray{
                    let name = marker["name"]
                }
            }
```

Here is how 'marker' looks in debug mode:
[image: markerScreenShot]

When I print marker, it prints the right content but unable to extract the data.

Any help will be really appreciated and already tried : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875394/swift-iterate-array-of-dictionaries)

Comment: How is your array declared in code? `[Any]` ? Because that's why

Comment: You just need to cast your array from `[Any]` to `[[String:Any]]`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956785/type-any-has-no-subscript-members

Comment: Btw you can make your life much easier structuring your data and making it conform to Codable.

Comment: @Vollan actually the array is received from another application.

Answer (score 0):

So i think your array consist of `[Any]` and will therefor not be able to use string key as it doesn't know it's a dictionary:

```
let array: [Any] = [["test": 12], ["testing": 2], ["12": 2]]
    for item in array {
        if let item = item as? [String: Any] {
            let name = item["test"]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you cast the array itself if all elements are probably dictionaries

Comment: @LeoDabus As the array is declared as `Any` i made a wild guess that it can have other value types as well. representing an entire json structure. But yes normally it would be the best way

Comment: @Vollan I tried this way also but it says " Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Any]'", So mean it's also not working in my case.